# How to make <v-layouts> not affect each other

Tags: html, typescript, vuetify.js

I'm creating a dynamic link box for a homepage site. It can be seen at https://gogia.github.io/escape/ Inside my link box I have a button that gives the ability to create buttons that act as links.

The layouts for the options button as well as the created buttons affect each other and I'm not quite sure why.

I've tried using multiple containers to decouple the layouts to no avail.

```
   <v-layout align-center>
      <v-btn
        dark
        class="accent--text"
        v-for="(item) in $store.state.linkStuff"
        :key="item"
        :href="item[1]"
      >{{item[0]}}</v-btn>
    </v-layout>

    <v-layout align-end justify-end>
      <v-icon color="info" @click="$store.state.coinMenu=true" v-ripple>mdi-currency-btc</v-icon>
      <v-icon color="info" @click="linkDialog=true" v-ripple>mdi-settings</v-icon>
      </v-layout>
```

Was not expecting these two separate layouts within one div to change the location of each other. There are no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed, the issue was where I put the container flags.

```
    <v-container>
    <v-layout align-center justify-space-around fill-height>
      <v-btn
        dark
        class="accent--text"
        v-for="(item) in $store.state.linkStuff"
        :key="item"
        :href="item[1]"
      >{{item[0]}}</v-btn>
    </v-layout>
    </v-container>


    <v-layout align-end justify-end>
      <v-icon color="info" @click="$store.state.coinMenu=true" v-ripple>mdi-currency-btc</v-icon>
      <v-icon color="info" @click="linkDialog=true" v-ripple>mdi-link-variant</v-icon>
      </v-layout>
```